# Hidden StatusBar in Expo React Native App Leaves Whitespace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

In our Expo React Native app, the status bar currently shown on all the app's screens. However, one screen *Welcome* needs to have the status bar hidden.

In the *Welcome* screen, dropping in `react-native`'s `StatusBar` component with `hidden` props set to `true` hides the status bar (on a physical iPhone) but leaves behind a white region.

**Problem:** This white region where the status bar used to be, should be transparent or removed to show the background image that is covering the rest of the screen.

How can we achieve this?

**Before hiding**

[image]

**After hiding**

*Note: Its hard to see the white region on the white background of Stack Overflow*

[image]

**Routes/index.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

...

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen,
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
})

...
```

**Welcome.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ImageBackground, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';

export class WelcomeScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <StatusBar hidden={true} />
                <SafeAreaView style={{height: '100%'}}>
                    <Layout style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <ImageBackground source={myBackgroundImage} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>

...
```

Using

- `react@16.8.3`
- `react-native@0.59.8` (Expo SDK 34 fork)
- `react-navigation@3.11.1`
- expo SDK 34

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this?

Comment: this issue still haunts me, no problem with iPhone but on Android it will leave a white bar on top of the screen

Comment: `<StatusBar hidden={true} />' is working for me

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the issue:

Replace

```
<StatusBar hidden={true} />
```

With

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor={'transparent'} translucent/>
```

Comment: I applied this hack to Android since the same thing happens but it problem is it doesn't enable proper interactions with the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

This may be and old question, but for the ones that still Googling it!

Change `<SafeAreaView>` for `<View>` or any other Surface. `SafeAreaView` still calculates the height of the StatusBar (even if it is hidden) and it applies a TopMargin to a normal view.

Comment: This doesn't change when on Android 11. Notch support on Expo seems problematic and we can't access Native files like on pure React Native.